# Why was this question closed as "opinion based"?

Tags: discussion

[This question](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/q/156611/88297) was closed fairly quickly as opinion based by users much higher rated than I, but I don't see where the opinion part is. Would anyone who downvoted care to explain?

It's probably off-topic for TWP, but I'm sure that this question has a very concrete economics answer based on past recessions (of which there have been at least 2 pops and a bubbles that I know of since software became more mainstream).

I imagine that a solid answer would look like:

> Study X shows that in recessions, A,B,C industries are hit harder than D,E,F industries. Additionally, the SO annual survey shows that employment rates for software engineers with G,H,I skillsets have shown increased amounts of unemployment during the J, K periods, but higher salaries during the L,M periods.

---

Note: I have edited the question in hopes of reopening, so here is the original text.

> Is there any general consensus on the more in demand fields of software engineering to pick up during a recession? I can see small business websites getting hit badly, so web dev is out. But is embedded facing the same headwinds?

Comment: it's a bit too complex to answer. No locale, no real idea of what the OP is asking and no two situations will be the same.

Comment: Asking for surveys or research tends not to be well-received. And sadly, we have a group of close-happy folks that rush to vote to close for almost any reason. I voted to re-open, even though I doubt the OP will get the kind of answer they are looking for.

Comment: @JoeStrazzere Sorry, the phrasing "Are there any studies" was added by me. I wanted to curve the question towards a more concrete answer, but it seems that hasn't been interpreted well!

Answer (score 4):

I wasn't a close voter - and while I don't think it's necessarily "opinion based" I think a concrete answer is going to require some pretty involved economic and market analysis backing.

Arguably it's less of "workplace navigation" question and more of an economics one - and perhaps that's a bit too far out of our wheelhouse to be considered on-topic.

Comment: Fair enough. I also think it would be better suited elsewhere, especially since answers here are usually more anecdotal than research based

Answer (score 0):

In my mind there isn't much about the question that isn't opinion based or that could not be "researched" by the OP themselves.

> Are there any studies or is there a general consensus on the more in
>   demand fields of software engineering to pick up during a recession?

Short answer here:  **Yes**, I am sure there are.  (laundry list type question)

> Anecdotally, I see small business websites getting hit badly, so web
>   dev is out. But does embedded face the same trends?

I doubt that there is a study or data that is specific to "*embedded face*".

While I did not vote to close this, and I agree that we do close some questions a bit to quickly, this one was justly closed from what I can see.

Comment: I'm pretty sure the OP meant "But does [the] embedded [software development domain] face the same trends?" and not "embedded face".

Comment: The two parts quoted are also parts I changed. Oops

Answer (score 0):

I think the core question is something like:

> I have skillset [set] and want to prepare better for the recession, what do?

However, the OP is asking for references or literature review. It is a valid question on something like [academia@SE](https://academia.stackexchange.com/) so probably should be valid here too. Voting to re-open